# removing Images on clicks in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am Trying to make a basic Hidden Object Game with kivy, But since i am a novice it is a little hard. So What I have done is using the canvas of flowLayout I have displayed 4 images, now I want them to disappear once I click **ON THEM**. how should I do this and what is the best way to achieve this???

Also another thing, I want a label to display a countdown. I have placed a Label But It isn't working. SO I just commented out it for the time being. If some one could please explain where I am going wrong.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')


running= True


class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):
    time_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_number = str(50)
    def call(self):
        if running:
            #print(self.time_number)
            #self.time_number = str(int(self.time_number)+1)
            pass            
    def clicked(self):
        global running
        #self.time_number = 50
        running=False

    Clock.schedule_interval(call, 1)

    pos1 =(0) #random.randint(-200,200)
    pos2 =(0) #random.randint(-200,200)

class WidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    WidgetsApp().run()
```

The .kv File

```
<MyWidget>
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:           
            Image:
                source:'B_image.png'
        BoxLayout:

            Label:
                text:root.time_number
        FloatLayout:
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    pos:(root.pos1,root.pos2)
                    size: 24, 24
                    source:'image.png'
                Rectangle:
                    pos:(root.pos1 + 100,root.pos2)
                    size: 24, 24
                    source:'image.png'
                Rectangle:
                    pos:(root.pos1,root.pos2 + 100)
                    size: 24, 24
                    source:'image.png'
                Rectangle:
                    pos:(root.pos1 + 100,root.pos2 + 100)
                    size: 24, 24
                    source:'image.png'
```

Comment: You should separate this post into two separate questions, since you're asking two questions in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each rectangle, set an on_press attribute to a function that removes the rectangle widget from its parent widget. Such as:

```
<MyWidget>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Image:
                source:'B_image.png'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:root.time_number
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            id: grid_layout
            Button:
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            Button:
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            Button:
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            Button:
                background_normal: 'image.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
```

And in main.py:

```
class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):
    ...
    def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
        self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
```

Comment: the function doesn't get called, I tried adding the above but it didn't worked.

then I added a print statement to the remove_rectangle() function so I know if it is being called when I click, but once I ran It and clicked on the Image It didn't did any thing.

Comment: Edited my response. The rectangle needs to actually be a Button or to subclass Button, so it has the on_press attribute. This is because for the rectangles to respond once you 'click on them', they need to have Button properties. Also, note the background_normal attribute.

Comment: Now I'm just getting this error

     kivy.lang.ParserException: Parser: File          "/home/nabeel/Desktop/widgets.kv", line 11:
          ...
                9:    value:root.time_number
               10:
          >>   11:  float_layout: float_layout
               12:
               13:  FloatLayout:
          ...
         Invalid data after declaration

I tried removing the "float_layout: float_layout" but then after clicking it just crashes with error <Attribute error : MyWidget has no attribute "float_layout">

Comment: Post the full traceback, using gist for example.

Comment: See the edited code. This will make your buttons disappear. You'll need to work on their positioning and sizing though.

Comment: Accept this as the answer if it works for removing the images.

Comment: Just click on the check box to the top left of the answer. Thanks.