# Updating text in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am working on a "Hidden Object game" under kivy. I have Implented the mathod discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660632/removing-images-on-clicks-in-kivy?noredirect=1#comment47463970_29660632)  and so far the objects get drawn and are removed once they are clicked. Now I am looking for a mathod which displays their names on screen as well and once the object is touched both the object and the corresponding label are removed.

How Do I achieve That???

I tried adding labels and then removing them using the same method I was using for the images but it is not working?

So My second guess was to write the names on a background in GIMP and then use those images. Is this approach fine or am I overseeing any simpler mathod?

### The .py File

```
__version__ = "1.0"

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')
ImagesList = ['calculator','cards','facebook','fly','glasses','keys','mouse','wallet','webcam','pen']      

running = True

class ImgButton(Button):
    pass

class ListLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):

    level = 1
    LOC = []
    for i in range (10):
        LOC.append((random.randint(50,400),random.randint(0,260)))

    num = 9

    b_G_IMG = StringProperty("Level1/B_image1.png")

    time_number = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.game_start()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.call, 1)

    def time_dec(self):
        if self. time > 0:
            self.time = self.time - 1
            self.time_number = str(self.time)
        else:
            self.running = False
    def game_start(self):
        self.time = 5
        self.time_number = str(self.time)
        self.level = 1
        self.running = True

    def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
        if self.running:
            if self.num > 0:
                self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
                self.num -= 1
            else:
                self.level += 1
                self.set_level(self.level)
                self.num  = 9
                for i in range(9):
                    new_image = ImgButton(background_normal= "Level1/"+str(ImagesList[i])+".png", pos = self.LOC[i])
                    self.grid_layout.add_widget(new_image)
                    new_image.bind(on_press=self.remove_rectangle)

        else:
            self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
            self.running = True
            self.game_start()


    def set_level(self,level):
        self.b_G_IMG = "Level"+str(level)+"/B_image"+str(level)+".png"


    def call(self,dt):
        if self.running:
            self.time_dec()
        else:
            game_image = Button(background_normal= "GameOver.png", pos = (40,40))
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(game_image)
            game_image.bind(on_press=self.remove_rectangle)



class WidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    WidgetsApp().run()
```

### The .kv File

```
<ListLabel@Label>
    halign:'left'
    font_size:15
    markup:True

<ImgButton@Button>:

    size_hint:(None,None)
    size:(60,60)


<MyWidget>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Image:
                source:root.b_G_IMG
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                pos:(-200,120)
                font_size: 33
                text:root.time_number

        FloatLayout:
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,20)
                text:'[color=000000]Calculator[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,10)
                text:'[color=000000]Cards[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,0)
                text:'[color=000000]facebook[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-10)
                text:'[color=000000]fly[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-20)
                text:'[color=000000]glasses[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-30)
                text:'[color=000000]keys[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-40)
                text:'[color=000000]mouse[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-50)
                text:'[color=000000]wallet[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-60)
                text:'[color=000000]webcam[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-70)
                text:'[color=000000]Pen[/color]'            

        FloatLayout:
            size:(480,320)
            size_hint:(480,320)
            id: grid_layout

            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[0])
                background_normal: 'Level1/pen.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[1])
                background_normal: 'Level1/cards.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[2])
                background_normal: 'Level1/calculator.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[3])
                background_normal: 'Level1/fly.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[4])
                background_normal: 'Level1/glasses.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[5])
                background_normal: 'Level1/keys.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[6])
                background_normal: 'Level1/mouse.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[7])
                background_normal: 'Level1/wallet.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[8])
                background_normal: 'Level1/webcam.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[9])
                background_normal: 'Level1/matches.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
```

> The Entire code and its assests are here if any one wants to take a
>   look and offer Advice
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zdes15h64cr3d8n/AAB7TG6Rab1UfIlF-2pX-cWZa?dl=0

Comment: Could you use the same the ImgButton class to create the labels also? Then you could use the exact same method of removal?

Comment: the main problem is relating the image to its label, So once the image is removed the text is also removed